# Is there a compact way to write a repeated if condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

Generally, there are two variations of writing repeated if conditions that I know of:

1. *Simple*

```
if x != <something> and x != <somethingElse> and x != <somethingElse +>:
```

2. *Little compact*

```
if all(x != el for el in [<something>, <somethingElse>, <somethingElse +>]
```

Is there a more compact way?

Comment: `x` should be equal to all three of them? That's... unusual.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for marking it out. In a hurry, wrote the wrong statement. Updated it. Thanks, again.

Comment: `x not in (something, somethingElse, ...)`…?

Comment: `x not in [<something>, <somethingElse>, <somethingElse +>]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `x` should not be in a group of things, the easiest solution is just:

```
if x not in (<something>, <somethingElse>, <somethingElse +>):
```

Expanding it for more items adds little verbosity, and it's relatively efficient, assuming the cost of computing each of the `something`s is small (it has to compute them all up front, but then, so does anything aside from one by one comparisons or complicated solutions involving programmatically generatable `something`s).

Comment: Thanks, nevertheless, your answer will be helpful, In a hurry I typed == instead of !=. So, if you can help with that. Thanks!

Comment: @Rabindra: Already edited it to answer the fixed question. :-) Though I would have just sent you to the duplicate had I read the fixed question initially.

Comment: Sure, thanks. While typing this question, I checked for similar questions. But didn't find any. So, went ahead with posting it.